# Getting items from an array with certain attributes and displaying them on one div

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

ex:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "grape",
      "color": "purple"
    },
    {
      "name": "apple",
      "color": "green"
    },
    {
      "name": "strawberry",
      "color": "red"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am looping through the array with this:

```
for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var item = "<button>"+data[i].name+"</button>";
  $('#items').append(item)
}
```

Let's say I want to have it so when you click on the button, display a `div` of the `color` value, but use the same `div` for every item in the array. How would I do this?

Comment: You are looping through an Array, but that's an Object with a `data` property, which contains an Array of Objects.

Answer (score 1):

Add an event handler to the buttons. It searches the `data` array for the object with the same name as the button text, and displays the color.

```js
var data = [{
    "name": "grape",
    "color": "purple"
  },
  {
    "name": "apple",
    "color": "green"
  },
  {
    "name": "strawberry",
    "color": "red"
  }
];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var item = "<button data-color=" + data[i].color + ">" + data[i].name + "</button>";
  $('#items').append(item)
}

$("button").click(function() {
  var name = $(this).text();
  var obj = data.find(el => el.name == name);
  $("#outputdiv").text(obj.color);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="items"></div>
<div id="outputdiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you but when I click the button and then go to click another its doesn't change the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a `click` event handler to each button as you create them, such that when that button is clicked, the event handler will format the target `<div>` with the specified item.

Here's a quick demo:

```js
const data = [{
    "name": "grape",
    "color": "purple"
  },
  {
    "name": "apple",
    "color": "green"
  },
  {
    "name": "strawberry",
    "color": "red"
  }
];

const displayDatum = (datum) => (event) => 
  $('#output').css({ background: datum.color }).text(datum.name);

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var item = $('<button>').text(data[i].name);
  item.click(displayDatum(data[i]));
  $('#items').append(item);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="items" />
<div id="output" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [
    {
      "name": "grape",
      "color": "purple"
    },
    {
      "name": "apple",
      "color": "green"
    },
    {
      "name": "strawberry",
      "color": "red"
    }
  ];

for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var item = "<button data-color="+data[i].color+">"+data[i].name+"</button>";
  $('#items').append(item)
}

$( "button" ).click(function() {
  $("#output" ).css('background', $(this).attr("data-color"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="items" />
<div id="output" style="width:100%; height:20px"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use pure js

```js
let d={"data":[{"name":"grape","color":"purple"},
  {"name":"apple","color":"green"},{"name":"strawberry","color":"red"}]}

let b= (i) => {
  box.style.background=d.data[i].color;
  box.innerText = d.data[i].name;
}

d.data.map((x,i)=>btns.innerHTML+=`<button onclick="b(${i})">${x.name}</button>`)
```

```css
#box { margin:10px; width:99px; height:99px; color:#fff; transition:1s }
```

```html
<div id="btns"></div>
<div id="box"></div>
```